# How to configure characters composition without the compose key

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout, compose-key

I have the US keyboard layout, and I need to use accented characters. I don't want to use the compose key, the system should be able to display the correct accented characters just by typing the appropriate sequence, as follows:

- `à`: type `` ` `` then `a`
- `á`: type `'` then `a`
- `â`: type `^` then `a`
- `ã`: type `~` then `a`
- `ç`: type `'` then `c`
- `'`: type `'` then `<space>`
- `~`: type `~` then `<space>`
- `''`: type `'` then `'`

... and so on. This behavior works fine on Windows, and it's the best configuration for people who uses accented characters frequently.

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04, but the preferred solution should work on any Ubuntu version.

Answer (score 2):

I have found the solution just by trying other options from **Settings > Region & Language**. The correct **Input Sources** is **English (US, intl. with dead keys)**:

[image: Region & Language dialog]

If the cedilla (`ç`) is not working:

1. Edit the file `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gtk-3.0/3.0.0/immodules.cache` and locate the line starting with `"cedilla"`. Add the locale `en` at the end of the last string, example:

   ```
   "cedilla" "Cedilla" "gtk30" "/usr/share/locale" "az:ca:co:fr:gv:oc:pt:sq:tr:wa:en"
   ```
2. Replace the character `ć` with `ç` in the Compose file:

   ```
   sudo sed -i /usr/share/X11/locale/en_US.UTF-8/Compose -e 's/ć/ç/g' -e 's/Ć/Ç/g'
   ```
3. Modify the file `/etc/environment` adding these lines:

   ```
   GTK_IM_MODULE=cedilla
   QT_IM_MODULE=cedilla
   ```
4. Reboot the system